# Local inner class

Tags: java, garbage-collection, inner-classes

I have read through inner class tutorial and don't understand one thing. It is being said that inner class holds hidden reference to outer class, so I come up with several questions via this plain class:

```
public class OuterClass {

public void doSomething() {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
      }
    });
  }
}
```

So we have one local inner class which resides inside method `doSomething()` and I have some questions involved.

1. Does this local inner class hold reference to OuterClass since it's local?
2. Does this local inner class remain memory after the method `doSomething()` terminates?
3. Is there any situation in which OuterClass is eligible for GC but local inner class still be referenced by other classes? What would happen?

Comment: you never voted nor accepted an answer to your previous questions. Please improve on that.

Comment: Nice question...at least for me.

Comment: I feel like upvoting this question but then looked at your profile and you have never accepted an answer or even worse never up voted anyone so sorry fallow you missed my upvote.

Comment: @Final: At least point 1 and point 3 of your question could have been solved by writing a simple test-program.

Comment: @Harry: you're voting on the question, not on the asker ;-) A good question deserves an upvote, even if the asker could improve in one way or another.

Comment: @Joachim: but question always belongs to an asker and I don't support people who keeps on gaining repu and privileges by only asking questions and never give upvote or accept answer.

Comment: Ok my fault but how can i upvote or accept answer? I'm newbie

Comment: @Harry: I understand where you're coming from and I'd also prefer if the OP would vote on and accept answers. But the fact that he doesn't do it (yet) doesn't make his answer any less valuable. It's nicely written and formatted and has a code sample to demonstrate what he means. That's above-average in my opinion and he deserves the rep he gains from it (in my opinion).

Comment: @Joachim: i couldn't find question on meta about upvote. Could you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes, the inner class has a reference to the `OuterClass` instance.

   You can verify that by accessing `OuterClass.this` in the method.
2. Yes, the inner class instance will continue to exist after the method terminates.

   Leaving the method does not influence the life-time of the object. Just as every other object, it will become eligible for GC once there are no more references to it. Since the `JButton` will hold a reference to it, it will stay in memory.
3. The `OuterClass` instance **can't** become eligible for GC as long as the inner class instance is reachable.

   The reason for that is #1: the inner class instance has a reference to the outer class instance, which means that the outer class can not become eligible for GC as long as the inner class is not eligible at the same time (i.e. *both* are no longer reachable).

Comment: That is actually not entirely true. Since the inner class in this case actually never references its enclosing `OuterClass` instance, no reference to it is compiled in. Therefore, in question 3, the answer is that the `OuterClass` instance *can* be GC'd even though the inner class remains referenced. That is, of course, particular to this case, but nonetheless.